# spring MVC + jsf + jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jsf-2

I am trying to integrate spring mvc with jsf and jquery.

The page shows only the hard-coded text, although the 3s timer is executed and the page is reRendered, however then the memory usage spikes up and everything starts to crash.
This is a sample page where a random number is supposed to be generated every 3 seconds

***Folder Structure***

```
-Web Content
   - index.xhtml
   - template.xhtml
   - rest
      - welcome.xhtml
   -WEB-INF
      - web.xml
      - testServlet-servlet.xml
      - faces-config.xml
      - lib
         - *all libraries*
-Java Resources 
   -src
      - com
         -controller
            -HelloWorld.java
```

***Template.xhtml***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' 
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div >
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </div>
 </h:body>
```

***Welcome.xhtml***

```
<ui:composition template="../template.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<ui:define name="title">
    Sample Page
    </ui:define>


<ui:define name="content">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'welcome.xhtml',
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var intervalId = 0;
        intervalId = setInterval(ajaxFunction, 3000);
    </script>

    ${message} 
    SUCCESS:
    <p id="result"></p>
</ui:define>
```

***Controller***

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("rest/welcome")
public class HelloWorld
{
    @RequestMapping("rest/welcome")
public ModelAndView ajaxTest()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("rest/welcome", "message",
                "This is a test message");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "rest/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getTime()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        float r = rand.nextFloat() * 100;
        String result = "<br>Next Random # is <b>" + r
                + "</b>. Generated on <b>" + new Date().toString() + "</b>";
        System.out.println("Debug Message from Controller.."
                + new Date().toString());
        return result;
    }
}
```

***Web.xml snippet***

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/testServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

***testSevlet-servlet.xml content***

```
     <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in welcome.xhtml is that
you are firing ajax to get same page i.e. welcome.xhtml

```
$.ajax({
                url : 'welcome.xhtml',
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
```

change  `url :'welcome.xhtml'` to  `url :'welcome'` to solve your problem (assuming you want to send ajax to `rest/welcome` )

Also you have put same requestmapping (rest/welcome) on Controller level as well as method level.I am not sure of your design but you can remove mapping from one of them

So change

```
@RequestMapping("rest/welcome")
public class HelloWorld
```

to

```
//RequestMapping("rest/welcome") note i have commented this
public class HelloWorld
```

Comment: i am getting no changes on the page and the following in console:////
Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW(1)////
Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE(6)////
DispatcherServlet with name 'testServlet' processing GET request for [/SpingMVCTestProject/rest/rest/welcome]////
Looking up handler method for path /rest/welcome////
Did not find handler method for [/rest/welcome]////
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI ////[/SpingMVCTestProject/rest/rest/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'testServlet'////
Successfully completed request

Comment: nothing happened and the console didn't output anything after Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_REPSONSE(6).

Comment: are u getting same result with url:'welcome' ?...you need to put correct url which will map to rest/welcome handler in your controller

Comment: with url:welcome i get the same as before with the difference being that the output in console changed paths: //// DispatcherServlet with name 'testServlet' processing GET request for [/SpingMVCTestProject/rest/welcome] ////
Looking up handler method for path /welcome ////
Did not find handler method for [/welcome] ////
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpingMVCTestProject/rest/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'testServlet'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35064/discussion-between-harrybvp-and-mangusbrother)